# Reset Form con jquery, vaciar input error Select2 elimina la lista

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, select2

estoy empleado el siguiente código:

```
$('#formarea')[0].reset();
```

Este me permite resetear un form pero en algunos caso no lo hace con los datos que han sido escritos con ajax o elementos agregados con ajax.

ademas me vacía los campos display none, hay alguna forma de parametrizarlo para que evite los campos display none. ademas los Campos con el plugging select2 no son enviados a mi php y antes de agregar esta linea de código si lo hacia

agregar una clase o limpiar campos por campos supondría editar mucho código, es un proyecto que tengo y van mas de 120 formularios diferentes. los inputs siguen el diseño de bootstrap.

**Codigo Actual:**

```
var formarea= $('#formarea *');
    formarea.not("[type=radio],[type=checkbox],[type=hidden],[readonly='readonly'],[style*='display: none'],.select2-offscreen,select").each(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        console.log(name);
        $(this).val('');
    });
```

he cambiado el codigo ya que no tenia el alcance que necesitaba, ahora la situación es que al emplearlo me elimina las opciones dentro del Select2

Comment: Prueba vaciando campo por campo los que tu quieras, o dales una clase especifica a los que te interesa y vacia por clase.

Comment: agregar una clase o limpiar campos por campos supondria editar mucho codigo, es un proyecto que tengo y van mas de 120 formularios diferentes. los inputs siguen el diseño de bootstrap.

Comment: creo que con el display="none" ; pero sucede principalmente con el pluging select2, si previamente tengo algo seleccionado el select no llega al php y antes de agregar esta linea si que lo hacia.

Comment: intentastes recorrerlo y si es hidden pasarlo algo como esto var `var formarea= $('#formarea');

$.each(formarea[0].elements, function(index, elem){
    //haz lo que quieras aqui
});`

Comment: @JackNavaRow estoy en eso pero como agrego un ".not" al ".each" deberia ir a la derecha o a la izquierda.

Comment: puedes agregar el ejemplo de lo que pase para ayudarte mejor

Comment: @JackNavaRow si ves actualmente ya me funciona pero el problema se mantiene con el plugging del select 2 que luego de correr la funcion me elimina todos los options de la lista :(

Comment: `$("#tu_select2").select2("val", "");` o puedes chequear esto https://stackoverflow.com/a/29854133/5695795

Comment: si ya lo mire y no esta relacionado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno despues de romperme la cabeza con el codigo logre esto:

```
$('#formarea :input').not("[type=radio],[type=checkbox],[type=hidden],[readonly='readonly'],[style*='display: none'],.select2-offscreen,[class^='select2'],select").each(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        console.log(name);
        $(this).val('');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Y en lugar de hacer tanto not, porque no incluyes solo los que quieres? Te dejo un ejemplo con un par de forms. No se si es exactamente lo que quieres, pero creo que podras sacar algo.

Lo que hago es, que el boton borrar busca en los form los input text e iguala su valor a nada.

```js
$('#borrar').click(function(){borrar();});

function borrar(){
$( "form input:text" ).val('');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Input Button">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="file">
  <input type="hidden">
  <input type="image">
  <input type="password">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="reset">
  <input type="submit">
  <input type="text" value="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA">
  <select>
    <option>Option</option>
  </select>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <button>ENVIAR</button>
</form>
<br/>
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Input Button">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="file">
  <input type="hidden">
  <input type="image">
  <input type="password">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="reset">
  <input type="submit">
  <input type="text" value="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA">
  <select>
    <option>Option</option>
  </select>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <button>ENVIAR</button>
</form>
<br/>
<br/>
<button id="borrar">BORRAR</button>
```

Comment: bueno me parece que no leiste los comentarios de el hilo principal ... hay explicopor que no uso el filtro de input:text...